# nginx - try_files does not return the default value

Tags: nginx

I have a fairly simple nginx configuration. 
I have 2 frontend applications (angular) and one backend application.

So, when I send a request to the url: `server_name/portal` the `index.html` is served from `/opt/folder1/portal/index.html`. 
When I send a request to `server_name/app` the `index.html` is served from `/opt/folder2/app/index.html`.

If I send the following request `server_name/portal/css/some_file.css` nginx correctly returns the file  `/opt/folder1/portal/css/some_file.css`.

Now, my problem is when I send a request for a file that does not exist.
For example, If I send the following get request: `server_name/portal/home` (this is a valid route in my angular application), the nginx returns 404.

As far as I understand, based on the defined `try_files` in the `location /portal` block, if nginx is unable to find the file in that location it should return the default value, which is `/opt/folder1/portal/index.html`.

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I tell nginx that if a file does not exist in the location, it should return a default `index.html` file?

My nginx version is `1.16.1` and my OS is `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`.

```
server {

  server_name <myIpAddress>;

  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    image/svg+xml;


  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8086/api;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }

  location /portal {
       root /opt/folder1;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }

  location /app {
      root /opt/folder2;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

  }

}
```

Comment: The URI for `/opt/folder1/portal/index.html` is `/portal/index.html` and not `/index.html`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it for me.